# Java initialize variables "remotely"

Tags: java, pointers, initialization

I need to initialize some variables I receive in an array like (example):

```
private Map<Long, Object> var1 = null;
private Map<Long, Object> var2 = null;
private Map<Long, Object> var3 = null;
private List<Map<Long, Object>> vars = Arrays.asList(var1, var2, var3);
```

And I would like to know if I can do this:

```
private void initializeVars() {
    var1 = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
    var2 = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
    var3 = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
}
```

But with something like this:

```
private void initializeVars() {
    for (Map<Long,Object> var : vars) {
        var = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work because underneath I'm just changing the pointer of the array position from 'var#' to a new HashMap, but what I want to do is access 'var#' and change its pointer.

Comment: Java does not have pointers, instead it has references.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're trying to achieve. Are you just trying to make a list of hash maps?

Comment: Can't you initialize the var1/2/3 to `new HashMap<Long, Object>()` directly instead of `null`? That way, changes in these maps will be visible in vars entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution that comes to my mind is packing it into another light-weight object, like `MyMap`. That `MyMap` would hold the actual map inside, and then you could initialize that map, something like this:

```java
private MyMap<Long, Object> var1 = new MyMap<>();
private MyMap<Long, Object> var2 = new MyMap<>();
private MyMap<Long, Object> var3 = new MyMap<>();
private List<MyMap<Long, Object>> vars = Arrays.asList(var1, var2, var3);

private void initializeVars() {
    for (MyMap<Long,Object> var : vars) {
        var.setInnerMap(new HashMap<Long, Object>());
    }
}
```

It's ugly and bad, but I don't see any different way right now. What you're trying with your way is certainly not possible in Java.

Comment: I had the same solution, a wrapper to set the reference later. There is a Class for this but I can't remember the name. In Java 8, Optionnal could be use for this I guess.

Comment: @AxelH: no, you can’t use `Optional` for this, as `Optional` is immutable.

Comment: @Holger, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you only receive an List of `null` so this could simply be a `int countVar = 3`, that would be the same.

But if you want to use this list.

```
private void initializeVars() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        list.add(new HashMap<Long, Object>());
    }
}
```

But of course, `var[1|2|3]` would still be null.

If you want to be able to do you logic, you would need a wrapper. See [Whatz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42720178/4391450) for that

Comment: That's basically what I wrote in my solution :p

Comment: @Whatzs yep, notice that after, I have removed that part. I took some time to write the full class ^^

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get, works with Java 8:

```
private Map<Long, Object> var1 = null;
private Map<Long, Object> var2 = null;
private Map<Long, Object> var3 = null;
private List<Consumer<Map<Long, Object>>> writers
        = Arrays.asList(m -> var1=m, m -> var2=m, m -> var3=m);

private void initializeVars() {
    for(Consumer<Map<Long,Object>> c: writers) {
        c.accept(new HashMap<>());
    }
}
```

You don’t have a field reference here, as a field reference would work in both directions. Here, we only have a `Consumer` encapsulating the operation of assigning a new value to the variable. For the initialization procedure, this is sufficient.